# C# if statement comparing text to array

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, textbox

Account Numbers are 6 digits in length when inserted into the array. They are stored as strings as they can begin with a 0.

As an example, I always use the Account Number of 123456, however, when I put that in the TextBox and click btnLogIn, it gives me an error.

`logInVerified` is a method that will show or hide another text box depending on the users input.

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < account.Accounts; i++)
    {
        if (txtAccountNum.Text == account.getAccountNumber(i))
        {
            logInVerified(true);
            txtBalance.Text = Convert.ToString(account.getBalance(i));
        }
        else if (i == account.Accounts)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No account found, please check Account and PIN numbers and try again.", "No account found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line? Your question is little bit unclear.

Comment: I believe that there is no error but that code is maybe incorrect. The Account number definitely exists however when I click the button I get the MessageBox to show up and if  I comment out the else if statement nothing happens at all.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with the debugger?  That would be the first thing to do - see what all the variables are and whether `txtAccountNum.Text` actually equals `account.getAccountNumber(i)` at any point.

Comment: _I get the MessageBox to show up_ this seems to be improbable giving the fact the loop exits when i is equalt to Accounts. Unless you change this value inside the getAccountNumber, logInVerified or getBalance....

Comment: Are you calling the `operator ==(object, object)` overload? It tests for reference equality (identical instances) only. The overload of `==` is statically (non-virtually) bound at compile-time.

Comment: The code does not work:
"i == account.Accounts", probably, you mean account.Accounts.Count

And ... the for-loop needs to be extended. 
"for (int i = 0; i < account.Accounts; i++)"
to "for (int i = 0; i <= account.Accounts; i++)"

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to declare my arrays as static. Fixed now, thanks for all the help guys :)